# Simplification for SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi all I have a requirement to round for the next multiple of 10. THis is the one I have written, so can any one suggest is there any simple way of executing the script

```
SELECT 10* ((FLOOR(ISNULL(MAX(118), 0) / CONVERT(FLOAT, 10)) + 
CAST(FLOOR(( ISNULL(MAX(118), 0) / CONVERT(FLOAT, 10)  -  FLOOR(ISNULL(MAX(118), 0) /      CONVERT(FLOAT, 10)) )  *  
POWER(10, 0)) / POWER(10, 0)  AS  FLOAT)) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it is working as well; but i'm not sure whether it's better than yours... ;-)

select 7 + case (10 - (7 % 10)) when 10 then 0 else (10 - (7 % 10)) end

select 9 + case (10 - (9 % 10)) when 10 then 0 else (10 - (9 % 10)) end

select 10 + case (10 - (10 % 10)) when 10 then 0 else (10 - (10 % 10)) end

select 18 + case (10 - (18 % 10)) when 10 then 0 else (10 - (18 % 10)) end

select 112 + case (10 - (112 % 10)) when 10 then 0 else (10 - (112 % 10)) end